# PL/SQL UPDATE/INSERT with table's variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

It is possible to build a statement using variables for the table name without creating a VARCHAR and using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE?

ex:

```
@table_name := test_table

UPDATE @table_name
SET col1 = val1
WHERE condition...;
```

this is my actual workaround:

```
DECLARE
  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
  table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'test_table';
BEGIN
  sql_stmt := 'UPDATE ' || table_name || ' SET col1 = val1...';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
END;
/
```

Comment: Your workaround is the solution. Let me rephrase that. Dynamic query is the solution. You may use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or `DBMS_SQL` to that end.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`?  You could, as @Sebas points out, use `DBMS_SQL` instead but that is unlikely to be the answer you're looking for.  You should use bind variables rather than assembling a string containing literals (like "val1") unless those really are constants that will never change.  It is pretty unusual, though, to know what columns need to be updated and what values need to be set without knowing what table needs to be modified-- the desire to use dynamic SQL often comes from trying to work around a data model problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "[Is it] possible to build a statement using variables for the table
>   name without creating a VARCHAR and using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE?"

No.

SQL is a strongly typed language.  The compiler requires the actual table name in order to validate the various components of the  SQL statement ( projection, filters, etc).

Dynamic SQL (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and DBMS_SQL) is necessary to short-circuit the compile time validation.  Essentially it's a mechanism relieving the compiler of the burden of verifying the SQL and taking it on ourselves (because humans are so much better at such jobs than machines. Not).

Alternatively, it's a mechanism for generating runtime errors instead of compilation errors.

Either way, it's pretty odd to know the name of the COLUMN in the filter but not the name of the TABLE being updated.